# How do I assign more weight or value relative to a fraction's denominator?

Tags: statistics

Is there a mathematical model where I can give more value if a denominator is larger? For instance, take 7/10 and 2/2, where the numerator is games won and the denominator is games played. In this case, the value of the fraction shows that 100% is > 70%. However, by just taking the value, people who do not play as many games will have a bias in their favor. Is there a that will make these conditions true:

| Games Played | Games Won | Win Rate | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 66% | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 100% | 4 |
| 0 | 1 | 0% | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 100% | 2 |
| 9 | 10 | 90% | 1 |

Comment: You can weight the entries however you choose.  Just select a vector of $5$ (or however many entries you have ) non-negative weights $(w_1, \cdots, w_5)$ and now take weighted averaged wherein you multiply each entry by the relevant weight.  Just be sure to divide by the weighted total when you compute the average.

Comment: @lulu How do I pick what my non-negative weights should be? If the entry has a length of 1000 with each a different value, how do I know which weight to multiply each entry by? Do I just assign an arbitrary value for weight?

Comment: That's not a math question.  There is no abstract notion that tells us which entries are more important to you and which ones less.  The usual thing one does is to try some simple proxy, like just weighting by the number of games played in your example.  Does that "work"?  Meaning, does that give results consistent with your intuition?  To be clear:  the more precisely you can specify your requirements, the easier it is to design the weighting function.

Comment: It is difficult to see how you might theoretically justify $2$ wins from $3$ played being seen as *better* than $1$ win from $1$ played, so the answer comes down to your personal opinions.  If those two had been the other way round, you could for example add some $k$ of your choice to the wins and $2k$ to the number played and so rank on $\frac{\text{wins}+k}{\text{played}+2k}$  which with any $k\ge 1$ would give your desired ranking